# How to remove extra decimal points?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to alter users input and leave in the box only integer or decimal values, i.e. 4567 or 354.5635. I use the following statement:

```
v = v.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, "");
```

But this allows multiple decimal points such as 345.45.345.67. How do I ensure that only one point is there?

Comment: If this is about the more general problem of checking if a string is numerical, regular expressions are not the best way - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: Why did you come to the conclusion that you need regular expressions here?

Comment: So if the user inputs `"5.5.5"` or `"5.5abc"` what should happen?

Comment: @Tomalak: it was kind of "obvious" :) Do I?

Comment: @Kizz: If it's so "obvious", how come it's wrong? :) What we need to take away from this is that your solution-selection protocol is broken.

Comment: @Šime: the box should change its value to "5.55" and "5.5"

Comment: @Kizz I've created this question to solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140612/remove-all-dots-except-the-first-one-from-a-string

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Your question is another prove of how important it is to phrase the title properly :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `parseFloat` here:

```
v = parseFloat(v);
```

This will guarantee you to have integer/decimal value or `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks @TomalakGeret'kal I misunderstood question a bit

Comment: No problem. :) [I could continue, by pointing out that decimal base is orthogonal from floating-point representation (and, if anything, "binary" would be appropriate), but I shan't...]

Comment: The project owner wants to replace all "wrong" input "on-the-fly" using txt's onblur and onkeyup handlers. I guess I either need to add some complicated logic to supplement that initial regex or I need to convince him to opt for a typical input validation and use parsing to test if the input is numeric.

Comment: @Kizz, you better add input validation during the input, but instead of editing user input, highlight error. For example, make `$(input).css('background','red')` when something wrong entered.

Answer (score 4):

`v = parseFloat(v).toFixed(numberOfDecimalDigits);`

Comment: parseFloat() is my favourite way, but be sure your float is small enough because parseFloat does not work well with high precision numbers like parseFloat('1.0000000000000001')

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if JS can do lookahead assertions, but if it can it could be done with a regex IF JS can also do reverse(input_string).

A reverse is needed because you want to allow the FIRST dot, and take out the rest.
However, search progresses left to right.

`/(?:[.](?=.*[.])|[^\d.])+/g` will take out all but the last '.'
So, the string has to be reversed, substituted, then reversed again.

Perl code example:

```
my $ss = 'asdf45.980.765';
$ss = reverse $ss;
$ss =~ s/(?:[.](?=.*[.])|[^\d.])+//g;
$ss = reverse $ss;
print $ss;
```

Output: `45.980765`

Comment: This is the best solution ever. Works like a charm in my js script.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = v.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""); 
     // This will replace the alphabets

v = v.replace(/[^\d]*(\d+(\.\d+)?)?.*/g, "$1"); 
    // This will replace other then decimal
```

Comment: These reg exps omits minus in negative values

Answer (score -1):

```
v = v.replace(/[^\d]*(\d+(\.\d+)?)?.*/g, "$1");
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It even allows letters. The idea of my expression is not to allow anything except for digits and a dot. Hense the ^ char. Thanks though.

Comment: Works for me: var v = ' 345.45.345.67';
v = v.replace(/[^\d]*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/g, "$1");
console.log(v); // Outputs 345.45

Comment: @Eugene: That's hardly a rigorous test. A breaking test is really easy to come up with: feed `"a"` to your regular expression.

Comment: Let's say that the user inputs the letter "H". I need to disallow that, allowing only integers and an optional singledot. Your expression doesn't do that: txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^\d]*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/g, ""); If the txt.value is "H", it stays "H", nothing gets replaced.

Comment: Choosing regular expressions for the task at hand is wrong, and this little trail of disasters is precisely why.

Comment: But how do you sanitize that input if it starts with a letter without regular expression?

Comment: @Tomalak: I think you are right. I'd probably switch to normal input validation on submit.

Comment: @Eugene: yko showed you half an hour ago: Javascript has had numeric parsing built-in for decades.

Comment: var v = 'a123.12';
v = parseFloat(v);
console.log(v); // Output - NaN

Comment: @Eugene: ... which is correct. Last I checked, `a123.12` is not a valid number. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Quote - "I need to alter users input and leave in the box only integer or decimal values, i.e.". We are talking about sanitizing user's input. "built-in numeric parsing" won't do the job.