# Remove all dots except the first one from a string

Tags: javascript, string

Given a string

```
'1.2.3.4.5'
```

I would like to get this output

```
'1.2345'
```

(In case there are no dots in the string, the string should be returned unchanged.)

I wrote this

```
function process( input ) {
    var index = input.indexOf( '.' );

    if ( index > -1 ) {
        input = input.substr( 0, index + 1 ) + 
                input.slice( index ).replace( /\./g, '' );
    }

    return input;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EDTNK/1/

It works but I was hoping for a slightly more elegant solution...

Comment: I think your existing solution is quite elegant.

Comment: I agree - your solution seems fine to me.

Comment: @Michael The solution uses `indexOf`, `substr`, `slice`, and `replace`, plus an `if` statement. I feel it's not as simple as I could be...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas But why do you feel it _needs_ to be simpler? Are you executing this thousands of times on a page, where speed becomes problematic?

Comment: @Michael I want to know the simplest way to do it. If there is a simpler (more advanced) way to do it, I want to know what it is. Making code simpler is one of the core values of programming, I believe.

Comment: I considered suggesting `str.reverse.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '').reverse` until I saw @bobble's recent answer, which is far better. Incidentally, I was just guessing at how the above would be written in Javascript, but the reader should get the idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be a lot easier with reg exp if browsers supported look behinds.

One way with a regular expression:

```
function process( str ) {
    return str.replace( /^([^.]*\.)(.*)$/, function ( a, b, c ) { 
        return b + c.replace( /\./g, '' );
    });
}
```

Comment: Some browsers support look backs?

Comment: whoops the all should have not been there. :)

Comment: I believe this is the definitive answer. The regular expression seems optimal.

Comment: @CarySwoveland did you try? The fact this is from 13 years ago... lol

Answer (score 21):

There is a pretty short solution (assuming `input` is your string):

```
var output = input.split('.');
output = output.shift() + '.' + output.join('');
```

---

If `input` is "`1.2.3.4`", then `output` will be equal to "`1.234`".

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxQXb/1/) for a proof. Of course you can enclose it in a function, if you find it necessary.

**EDIT:**

Taking into account your additional requirement (to not modify the output if there is no dot found), the solution could look like this:

```
var output = input.split('.');
output = output.shift() + (output.length ? '.' + output.join('') : '');
```

which will leave eg. "`1234`" (no dot found) unchanged. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxQXb/2/) for updated code.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I would like this to also work in the case that there are no dots (in which case the input should be returned unchanged)...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: My solution for now solves only the issues you did not forgot to mention. I will take a look at it and try to take this into account.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Done, please review.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\./,"#").replace(/\./g,"").replace(/#/,".");
```

But you have to be sure that the character `#` is not used in the string; or replace it accordingly.

Or this, without the above limitation:

```
str = str.replace(/^(.*?\.)(.*)$/, function($0, $1, $2) {
  return $1 + $2.replace(/\./g,"");
});
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: might be; but, after seeing all the great answers here, I'm pretty sure there's _no definitive way_ to do it.

Comment: I've accepted an similar answer which uses a slightly more accurate regular expression, I believe.

Comment: It all depends. The regex I used is more generic, it works with strings like `"."`, `".1.2.3"` and `"123."`; but I don't know if you have those as input.

Comment: The other answer uses `+` instead of `*` quantifiers. But it's the `[^.]+\.` or `[^.]*\.` construct that I believe is more accurate. The idea is to match all characters up to the first dot, and this construct is I believe the most proper way to do this. You use the `.` (any character) combined with a non-greedy quantifier which I think produces the exact same result. However, it does not convey its meaning as accurately as the other construct. (But I'm a regexp noob so I might be wrong `:)`).

Comment: Do you ever have strings as the ones I've described?

Comment: Only the trailing dot example (`'123.'`) since that one is a valid *NumericLiteral* in JavaScript (`123. === 123`)

Comment: Then you're covered for that one (I had mistakenly though it wasn't covered). But, a number with a leading dot is also a valid numeric literal in Javascript

Comment: Ewww, has that been whupped with an ugly stick or what?

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

I didn't find any solution that would solve this using a single regex replace, so there is a solution using a negative lookbehind, a global capturing flag to match all the dots except the first one after the first digit on the beginning of the string with an optional minus character support.

#### Javascript example

```js
    let str = "-134.2.3.4.5"
    str.replace(/(?<!^-?\d+)\./g, '')
```

#### Explanation

- Thanks to the `?<!` notation, the negative lookbehind makes sure that the regex will not match the first dot after the `^-?\d+` pattern. So, it will not match anything where we have, e.g. `-124` or `12` on the beginning of the string.
- After that, there is a `\.` matching, so it will basically try to match the dots. With the connection of negative lookbehind, the first dot will be always ignored, so it will match 2nd and all subsequent dots.
- Then, the `\g` flag makes sure that the `replace` function will execute for all matches, not only the first one.
- At the very end, the `replace` is replacing all the dot characters with an empty whitespace which produces an expected output.

#### Risks

Note that negative lookbehind is a fancy feature and as it should be already supported by most of the browsers, there can be some cases for especially older nodejs versions or legacy browsers where the solution will not work as expected. You can refer to the following websites to make sure it will work fine on your platform.

- https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookbehind_assertion
- https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions

Comment: Good job. I wasn't aware that Javascript supported variable-length lookbehinds. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBaYAQ/1).

Comment: If desired, you could generalize that using `(?<!^[^.]*)\.` so that the first period--the one to be kept--could be preceded by more than just `-?\d+`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pTaafT/1). It appears, incidentally, that when this question was posted Javascript didn't support lookbehinds, much less, variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it's a very good idea to generalise this approach to be used in sentences, however, I feel like the regex would need to be more sophisticated, as notice that with the example that you provided, all the dots will be replaced - you will not be able to create a sentence and place a dot as you would usually do. Based on your example, I created another pattern that should opt for all these cases ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4jtQ2E/2)): `(?<!(?:^|\s)[^.]*)\.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this, i also don't know if this is "simpler", but it uses just indexOf, replace and substr.

```js
var str = "7.8.9.2.3";
var strBak = str;

var firstDot = str.indexOf(".");
str = str.replace(/\./g,"");
str = str.substr(0,firstDot)+"."+str.substr(1,str.length-1);

document.write(str);
```

Shai.

Comment: There still are four method invocations (`indexOf`, `replace`, and `substr` twice). I would like to cut this number down to 1-2 invocations...

Comment: This is broken. For `"abcd.efgh"` the part `str.substr(1,...)` is clearly wrong. Also doesn't work when the strings has no dots.

Comment: This was of course just the basic test for his specific test case, as i always say - i dont right solutions, i right direction. SO is not about writing solutions for people, its about sharing ideas and experience (thats how i see it at least).

Anyways, as i said i dont think its better, and if its, probably not by much.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily more elegant, but it's another way to skin the cat:

```
var process = function (input) {
    var output = input;

    if (typeof input === 'string' && input !== '') {
        input = input.split('.');
        if (input.length > 1) {
            output = [input.shift(), input.join('')].join('.');
        }
    }

    return output;
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention but I would like this to also work in the case that there are no dots (in which case the input should be returned unchanged)...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
function process(input) {
    var n = 0;
    return input.replace(/\./g, function() { return n++ > 0 ? '' : '.'; });
}
```

But one could say that this is based on side effects and therefore not really elegant.

Comment: The callback depends on and changes the `n`... I assume this could be considered as side effect.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the part until the *first* dot:

```js
let s = '1.2.3.4.5';

s = s.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\./g,'$1');

console.log(s);
```

Also see [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wng0jx/1)

- `^([^.]*\.)` the [first group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982824/what-does-1-2-etc-mean-in-regular-expressions) at [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) *captures* any characters [that are not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a dot until first `.`
- `|\.` [OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) *match* (don't capture) any remaining periods

Replace with `$1` which contains a dot if the left side of the *alternation* matched, else empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is supposed to happen if "." is the first character, I'd check for -1 in indexOf, also if you use substr once might as well use it twice.

Javascript:

```
if ( index != -1 ) {
    input = input.substr( 0, index + 1 ) + input.substr(index + 1).replace( /\./g, '' );
}
```

Kotlin:

```
// preprocess for input like ".1234", "..1234" ...

val indexOfFirstDot = input.indexOf('.')
if (indexOfFirstDot != -1) {
      output = StringBuilder()
                       .append(input.substring(startIndex = 0, endIndex = indexOfFirstDot + 1))
                       .append(input.substring(startIndex = indexOfFirstDot + 1).replace(".", ""))
                       .toString()
} else {
      output = input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = s.indexOf(".");
var result = s.substr(0, i+1) + s.substr(i+1).replace(/\./g, "");
```

Somewhat tricky. Works using the fact that `indexOf` returns -1 if the item is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep this as short and readable as possible, you can do the following:

**JavaScript**

```
var match = string.match(/^[^.]*\.|[^.]+/g);
string = match ? match.join('') : string;
```

Requires a second line of code, because if `match()` returns *null*, we'll get an exception trying to call `join()` on *null*. (Improvements welcome.)

**Objective-J / Cappuccino** *(superset of JavaScript)*

```
string = [string.match(/^[^.]*\.|[^.]+/g) componentsJoinedByString:''] || string;
```

Can do it in a single line, because its selectors (such as `componentsJoinedByString:`) simply return *null* when sent to a *null* value, rather than throwing an exception.

As for the regular expression, I'm matching *all* substrings consisting of either (a) *the start of the string + any potential number of non-dot characters + a dot*, or (b) *any existing number of non-dot characters*. When we join all matches back together, we have essentially removed any dot except the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = '14.1.2';
reversed = input.split("").reverse().join("");
reversed = reversed.replace(\.(?=.*\.), '' );
input = reversed.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tadek's answer above. This function takes other locales into consideration.

---

For example, some locales will use a comma for the decimal separator and a period for the thousand separator (e.g. `-451.161,432e-12`).

First we convert anything other than 1) numbers; 2) negative sign; 3) exponent sign into a period (`"-451.161.432e-12"`).

Next we split by period (`["-451", "161", "432e-12"]`) and pop out the right-most value (`"432e-12"`), then join with the rest (`"-451161.432e-12"`)

(Note that I'm tossing out the thousand separators, but those could easily be added in the join step (`.join(',')`)

```
var ensureDecimalSeparatorIsPeriod = function (value) {
    var numericString = value.toString();
    var splitByDecimal = numericString.replace(/[^\d.e-]/g, '.').split('.');
    if (splitByDecimal.length < 2) {
        return numericString;
    }
    var rightOfDecimalPlace = splitByDecimal.pop();
    return splitByDecimal.join('') + '.' + rightOfDecimalPlace;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "12.1223....1322311..";

let finStr = str.replace(/(\d*.)(.*)/, '$1') + str.replace(/(\d*.)(.*)/, '$2').replace(/\./g,'');

console.log(finStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [integer, ...decimals] = '233.423.3.32.23.244.14...23'.split('.');
const result = [integer, decimals.join('')].join('.')
```

Same solution offered but using the spread operator.
It's a matter of opinion but I think it improves readability.