# How can i restrict entering more than one dots in input type number field in react js?

Tags: javascript, numbers

> Only one dots will allow in input type number field in react JS.
>   Anyone please???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140612/remove-all-dots-except-the-first-one-from-a-string

Comment: Look ^^^^^ at that guys code. Set the `input` to run through that function `onChange` and then set the value of the input after it has been cleaned.

Comment: Thanks. But i need to restrict before entering next dot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all dots except the first one from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140612/remove-all-dots-except-the-first-one-from-a-string)

Comment: haha @RaviKumarGopalakrishnan I linked the same answer...

Comment: "restrict" to require entering more than one, or "restrict" to prevent entering more than one? I'm assuming prevent, but it's better to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to apply validation

```
(/\.\./g).test("12..3")
(/\.\./g).test("12.3")
```